# NOQUEUE: SYSERR(www-data): can not chdir(/var/spool/mqueue-client/): Permission denied

Tags: permissions, users, sendmail

Here's the folder:

```
drwxrws---  2 smmsp smmsp 4096 May 25 22:47 mqueue-client/
```

So I did this...

```
usermod -a -G smmsp www-data

# groups www-data
www-data : www-data smmsp
```

But I still get this error in mail.log

```
sendmail[13152]: NOQUEUE: SYSERR(www-data): can not chdir(/var/spool/mqueue-client/): Permission denied
```

What's your recommendation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Purging and reinstalling sendmail was the solution. And turns out I didn't need Postfix, so that might have been part of the problem too. I'm not exactly sure though.

```
apt-get purge sendmail sendmail-cf m4 postfix
```

In any case, it wasn't necessary for me to modify the www-data user.